# ROracle not fetching full text variable

Tags: r, database, oracle11g, roracle

I am trying to fetch data from Oracle DB using ROracle. One of my variables is long string variable but when I am using fetch(var) its randomly snipping the variable. Any one else getting similar problem?

Comment: Snipping randomly, or after 4000 characters (or bytes)?

Comment: Its snipping it randomly.. For example: for first row, the actual string is "(Amended) Gene" but it only fetching "(Amen"

Comment: I ended up using RODBC and it has resolved my problem. I think there is encoding problem when connecting to ODBC using ROracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using RODBC and it has resolved my problem. I think there is encoding problem when connecting to ODBC using ROracle.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem with `NCLOB`

On one PC return full text on other only part.

Solved by convert `TO_CLOB(` in sql

May be your have `nvarchar` column, try to convert `TO_CHAR`